# tagName not initiating a new el element in subview; it inherits from the parent view

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I have a setup like this:

```
define(['Backbone','text!../templates/contacts.html'],function(Backbone,templ){

var view=Backbone.View.extend({
template:_.template(templ),
el:"#mainContainer",

render:function(){
header=new headerView({tagName:'h1'});
console.log(header.render().el);
this.$el.append(header.render().el);
this.$el.html(this.template);

}

});


var headerView=view.extend({

tagName:'h1',

render:function(){this.$el.html("Header View")

//console.log(this.el)

return this;
}

})

return view;
})
```

In the console i expect to get `<h1>Header View</h1>` but i get the div container with id "mainContainer"

Where i am going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used already existing element - `el:"#mainContainer"`. That is why you cannot change its tag - it's already defined. If you comment this line - all will work as you expect.

Comment: but i need different els for both the views! can't i overwrite in the subview?

Comment: Remove the line I mentioned above. Render a view - `view.render();`. Append it to the element you want - `$('#mainContainer').append(view.$el)`

Comment: yeah it works. Is it the right way to do things? I am a bit new to structuring the apps :(